# "Actions" menu hidden in Report Viewer web part?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, reports

The Actions menu which allows for export to excel, pdf and other functions is hidden in all of my report viewer web parts.

I did try to browse to the web part galleries to see if I can set it up there, but I just get an error message on clicking on Report Viewer.dwp

"Error 
This web part has not been configured correctly. Please contact the document owner. 
"
I am running SSRS on Sharepoint 2010 in integrated mode. 
Please advise.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem.